# Mac Terminal problem

Tags: iphone, macos, command-line

I'm trying to execute this line:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols
```

but this error pop out:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either escape the space and both the opening and closing parens with a backslash like this:

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1\ \(8C148\)/Symbols
```

or quote the path like this:

```
cd "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols"
```

Escaping and quoting seems tedious and annoying, you might say? Rest assured, there is a better way. Power users generally rely on [tab completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_completion) and don't really think about escaping paths on the command line too much. Try typing the first part of a directory or filename and hit the `tab` key. You'll see the shell auto-complete as much of the text as possible. If there is still more to type, hit the `tab` key again and you'll be presented with a list of possible matches based on what you've typed so far. Type more characters to disambiguate and try hitting `tab` again. Rinse and repeat as necessary. Tab completion will do the escaping for you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1\ \(8C148\)/Symbols

Comment: Note the \ before the space and before each of the parentheses.  The other way to do it without the \ character is to enclose the whole thing in "quotes".